# Notepad++ Поставить двойные кавычки при нахождении символа

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

дано:
csv файл в котором 500 строк информации
Какой поиск и замену можно сделать в notepad++ через регулярные выражения или через расширенные, чтобы при нахождении в строке определенного символа (Системные символы ", ', >, <, &) он проставил двойные кавычки в начале и конце строки? И чтобы не думблировал их, если они уже стоят.
Пример:

```
До:
0104603702762113215qj6cNs4rKxfQ
0104603702762113215FG6z)r(l,>1a
0104603702762113215y6J/X4L&sN-B
0104603702762113215oDkQqvP:/UXE
0104603702762113215LBT-fDGdwt9K
0104603702762113215Bb-XVT2Nzn;Y
0104603702762113215JBUVwSR%LiUk
0104603702762113215+8TMGXu;pFv"
0104603702762113215kIZw=!("ftkM
0104603702762113215ZBFp6R,oE"C>
0104603702762113215dn%.YsAQMKNa
0104603702762113215>tklJqLXn(jb

После:
0104603702762113215qj6cNs4rKxfQ
"0104603702762113215FG6z)r(l,>1a"
"0104603702762113215y6J/X4L&sN-B"
0104603702762113215oDkQqvP:/UXE
0104603702762113215LBT-fDGdwt9K
0104603702762113215Bb-XVT2Nzn;Y
0104603702762113215JBUVwSR%LiUk
"0104603702762113215+8TMGXu;pFv""
"0104603702762113215kIZw=!("ftkM"
"0104603702762113215ZBFp6R,oE"C>"
0104603702762113215dn%.YsAQMKNa
"0104603702762113215>tklJqLXn(jb"
```

Comment: Вероятно, это требуется для импорта? тогда закавычивай всё - на импорт строк, не содержащих служебные символы, это не повлияет. А вот двойную кавычку внутри значения нужно квотить, иначе импорт выполнится неверно.

Comment: Не, если в кратце, это для массового формирования наборов через загрузку на честном знаке, я уже пробовал ставить двойную везде и экранировать внутри, но при загрузки ЧЗ выдаёт ошибку. Как ответил их техпод, нельзя заковычить вообще всё подряд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для поиска нажать `ctrl+h`
В строке Найти:

```
(?=.*["'><&])^(.*)$
```

В строке заменить:

```
"\1"
```

*Обязательно должен быть выбран режим поиска **"Регулярные выражения"** и убрана галочка **"И новые строки"***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Коротко о регулярном выражение:

`(?=.*["'><&])` позитивный просмотр вперед, где проверяем наличие символов по условию в строке.

- если таких нет, то переходим к следующей строке
- если такие символы есть, то переходим к следующей части:
- - `^(.*)$` от начала до конца захватываем всю строку и возвращаем ее с кавычками.

Comment: И активировать "Регуляр.выражен.", а то по умолчанию стоит "обычный"

Comment: @Эникейщик, я для этого скриншот приложил, но сейчас добавлю предупреждение текстом, спасибо!

Comment: это какая версия? У меня при выборе регулярных выражение опция "только целые слова" становится неактивной, а тут активная.

Comment: @Эникейщик, версия 7.9, но после переключения режима "Регулярные выражения - Обычный - Регулярные выражения" у меня тоже стала неактивной...